# Should a "How to" or similar prefix be removed when editing question titles?

Tags: discussion

A lot of questions are posted which have a prefix similar to:

1. "How to" upload image from computer?
2. "How do I" set the date modified?

Should these prefixes be left when editing a question?

Personally, I feel that:

> Load an external dll

...is better than:

> How to load an external dll

I understand that this question might be subjective but I am asking in case there is a de-facto adopted by the majority.

Comment: "loading an external dll" is IMO better

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though many questions can benefit from a more descriptive title, I see little difference between:

#### How to upload image from computer?

And:

#### Upload image from computer?

In terms of what it brings to the reader.

This is a matter of personal preference and style - I don't think such titles merit edits.

Comment: I agree that they wouldn't merit edits in their own right, I think I find myself asking the question when editing a post for another reason.  So, more of an additional change.

Comment: @Ste - If it bothers you so much, change the titles. And if already changing them, make them more relevant to the question...

Comment: thanks, I'm rather apathetic to the title scenario but, in trying to do my bit for the community, I thought I'd ask what was best.  You've answered my question so shall get the checkmark.  Maybe I'll get another downvote though and I can get my "Peer pressure" badge!

Comment: If I really had to choose between those two, I'd rather use the first wording with the "how to" in it.

Comment: @Ste - [Downvotes on meta are different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @Oded - Thanks for the further info.

Comment: @Alenanno - And others would rather not see it... That's my point about personal preference.

Comment: @Oded Yes but the second one sounds like when you are talking and you suddenly decide to ask a question instead of just stating something so you just raise the tone (without the verb inversion or other similar things). :D